# Template or tool for creating single-page multimedia presentations?

Tags: website-design, template-design

Some examples I have in mind are:

- [The next America](http://www.pewresearch.org/next-america/), Pew Research
- [A game of Sharks](http://www.nytimes.com/newsgraphics/2013/10/27/south-china-sea/), The New York Times
- [Recalling a Vision of the Future](http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2014/04/20/nyregion/worlds-fair-1964-memories.html), The New York Times

How would you create something like this with minimal effort? Is there a tool or a template? What I particularly don't want to do is to hack away in HTML/CSS, Javascript, or jQuery. If there was only something a bit higher level so I could concentrate on the content while getting such results...

Comment: is this presentation for display on the web i.e a website or are you giving a presentation?

Comment: On the Web. Maybe I should have said _articles_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're best off going with WordPress and buying a template, here are some examples:

- http://themeforest.net/item/haven-elegant-one-page-wordpress-theme/6562851
- http://themes.designova.net/?theme=dignity-wordpress
- http://demo.themevan.com/preview.php?theme=simplekey

Comment: I'm not going to install WP just for this, but thanks for pointing out that I want a one-page template; it lead me to [this](http://onepagelove.com) and [that](http://designscrazed.com/flat-onepage-responsive-html5-templates/).

Comment: No problem, glad it got you going in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

> How would you create something like this with minimal effort?

Depends on what you mean by 'like this'.

The NYTimes hires talented interaction designers that create those presentations. They aren't from a template, but created based on the context of each story.

Broadly speaking, it's HTML5, CSS and JS.

So, yea, to really do that kind of custom work, you do need to be able to "hack away in HTML/CSS, Javascript, or jQuery".

Like most web design over the past 10-20 years, you either pick a template and live within the confines of the template, or you DIY by hacking away.

There are some tools out there that can help with parts of this, however. For example, [Adobe's Edge Animate](http://html.adobe.com/edge/animate/). I can't say how good it is. I'm skeptical, as I've never been impressed with software than auto-generates HTLM and CSS, but might be something worth looking at.

Side note: While those types of presentations are visually stunning, they aren't always the most usable way to present content. Often people just want to read the story...not have to scroll through pages of sliding bells and whistles. Something to consider.

Answer (score 0):

With tools today like bootstrap and jquery making interactivity so easy a little time in css can get you where you need to be without having to worry about the confines of a template or bring known for implementing a template (which I find can be just as bad).   What no one wants to admit is that if you aren't willing to figure out the JS, JQuery, CSS etc. then you are limiting the amount of design that you can even employ.

What you need to do as a designer is be able to handle the technical to achieve the design.

http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/
http://jquery.com/

Also great resource to start 'hacking' your way to a design is w3School too.    Don't avoid learning these things!   Without them you are only a template peddler.

Otherwise use prezi.com

Seriously got me through college with outstanding presentation each time - very different style from what you have posted but check it out anyway - please.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Microsoft Office license, they just released a new tool called Sway which is somewhat similar to these examples.

https://sway.com/

Another impressive tool that is more slide/presentation based is impress.js
Which requires some coding or you could use an online editor to create it like:

http://strut.io/